# Position for arrow up and arrow down originally in single gif inside a Sprite image

Tags: css, css-sprites

I replaced [Polyglot](http://www.ixtendo.com/demo/polyglot-language-switcher-jquery-plugin-2.0/index.html) dropdown arrow with sprite-css image. I can show arrow up but not hover arrow down image (left bottom) because it is single gif image:
http://www.bestjob.my/mod/LanguageSwitcher/images/arrow-down.gif

```
#polyglotLanguageSwitcher a.current:link span.trigger, #polyglotLanguageSwitcher a.current:visited span.trigger {
background: url(http://www.bestjob.my/mod/CSS/sprites/spriteme2b.png) no-repeat;background-position: 0px -37px; 
}

#polyglotLanguageSwitcher a.current:hover span.trigger, #polyglotLanguageSwitcher a.current:active span.trigger, #polyglotLanguageSwitcher a.active span.trigger {
background-position: left bottom !important;
}
```

Any advise? Do I need to cut arrow up and hover arrow down into 2 png and then put into sprite image for different background position?

Comment: Your examples are pretty weird, you show some different image, you are using some different image and there's no up arrow image in the provided 2 images

Comment: Pls take a look at arrow-down.gif. It include arrow up at the top and arrow down at the left bottom. For example pls take a look at:http://www.ixtendo.com/demo/polyglot-language-switcher-jquery-plugin-2.0/index.html